# Prevent duplicate entry in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to add rule so that no duplicate rdate is added in database.
I am beginner to firebase and i don't know how to create rules for stopping duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with security rules, because rules don't have a way of performing queries for other nodes.  The only way you can access other nodes in the database is using [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#val) at the specific location you're interested in knowing about, but you have to know the full path to that specific location.

Your alternative is to make a request through a backend you control (such as Cloud Functions), and have that backend perform the query to check if there is a conflict.

Comment: what if we know the full path like here   `".write":"root.child('NEWSCROW').child('news_item').child('navbharttimes').child('$').child('rdate').val()===newData.child('rdate').val()"`